# css for all other browsers but IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, layout

The problem i am having is I have a simple floated layout with the s3slider plugin installed within one of the content divs

It works fine in internet explorer but all other browsers (chrome, ff, opera) have a left-margin of about 40px and a top margin of about 15px. I can figure out why so i was wondering if there was a way to add left:-40px; top:-15px; to only be read by all browsers but IE.

The other problem is that the width of the slider is smaller in width that its container which matches perfectly in IE. I still havent figured out a fix for this.

**MAIN CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background:#AECF76;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
input[type=submit]{
float:right;
padding:10px;
font-size:14px;
background:#595959;
border:0px;

color:#E4EFD1;
font-weight:bold;
margin-top:10px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
}

input[disabled=disabled] {
border:0px;
background:0px;
}
input[disabled] {
border:0px;
background:0px;
}
.edit {
border:1px solid red;
background:#FFF;
color:#333;
font-weight:bold;
margin-right:5px;
padding:5px;
}
h1{
font-size:18px; 
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
h2,h3{
font-size:16px; 
padding:0px;
margin:0px; 
}
h4,h5,h6{
font-size:14px; 
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
/* SIZE TABLE */
.cbox{
 display:none;  
}.sizetable input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
/************/
#container{
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;  /**/
/*left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;*/
}

#header{
width:900px;
float:left; 
-moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
border-radius::4px 4px 0 0;
}
#header img{

-moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
}
#content{
width:900px;
float:left; 
border:1px solid black;
background:#fff;
}
.leftNavContainer{
 width:200px;

 float:left;    
}
.leftNavHeader{
 width:180px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:14px; 
background:#595959;
color:#E4EFD1;
 float:left;
 }
.leftNav{
 width:200px;
 float:left;
 height:auto;
 }

 .leftNav ul{
margin:0px; padding:0px;list-style-type:none;}

.leftNav li a{
background: #E4EFD1;
   color: #333;
   display: block;
   text-decoration:none;
   width: 185px;
   padding:5px;
   padding-left:10px;
}
.leftNav li a:hover{
background: #666;
   color: #E4EFD1;


}

.smallblock{
width:680px;
padding:10px;
float:left; position: relative;  /*important */
}
/*            */
.shadebox{
width:160px;
padding:10px;
float:left;
background:#fff;
}
.shadeboxsml{
width:60px;
padding:10px;
float:left;
background:#fff;
}
.name{
width:155px;
padding-top:10px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
background:#fff;
}
.shadebox .info{
width:160px;
float:left;

}
.shadebox .left{
width:37px; 
float:left;

}
.shadebox .front{
width:74px; 
float:left;
padding:13px 5px 0px 5px;

}



/*                */
.tableHead{
width:835px; 
float:left; padding:10px;border:1px solid #AECF76; background:#666; color:#E4EFD1; font-weight:bold;border-bottom:0px;margin-top:10px; display:inline;-moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;   font-size:14px;
}
.tableHeadsml{
width:680px; 
float:left;   padding:10px;background:#E4EFD1;color:#7BA235; margin-top:10px; display:inline;
}
.fullblock{
width:880px;
padding:10px;
float:left; 
}
#footer{
width:880px;
padding:10px;
float:left;
background:#E4EFD1; 
-moz-border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

**CSS FOR SLIDER**

```
 #slider {
    width: 680px; /* important to be same as image width */
    height: 256px; /* important to be same as image height */
    position: relative; /* important */
    overflow: hidden; /* important */
    float:left;

}

#sliderContent {
    width: 680px; /* important to be same as image width or wider */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    float:left;
}
.sliderImage {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: none;

}
.sliderImage img{border:0px;}
.sliderImage span {
    position: absolute;
    font: 12px/15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 660px;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    padding-bottom:14px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.sliderImage span strong {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.top {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

ul { list-style-type: none;}
```

**FULL PAGE CODE**

```
<?php 
include"inc/config.php";
include"inc/classes.php"; 
$page = new Page;
$details = $page->Details('home');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<!-- Start JS Plugins-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/shadesizes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/s3Slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').s3Slider({
            timeOut: 6000
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- END Plugins -->
<!-- Start Stylesheets -->


<link href="styles/nmain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles/table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#slider {
    width: 680px; /* important to be same as image width */
    height: 256px; /* important to be same as image height */
    position: relative; /* important */
    overflow: hidden; /* important */
    float:left;

}

#sliderContent {
    width: 680px; /* important to be same as image width or wider */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    float:left;
}
.sliderImage {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: none;

}
.sliderImage img{border:0px;}
.sliderImage span {
    position: absolute;
    font: 12px/15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 660px;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    padding-bottom:14px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.sliderImage span strong {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.top {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

ul { list-style-type: none;}
</style>
<!-- END Stylesheets -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Wind Blocker Sun Shades - <?php echo ucwords($details['title']);?></title>
</head>
  <body>
<div id="container">

        <?php include"inc/header.php";?>
    <div id="content">

        <!-- START LEFT NAV -->
        <?php include"inc/nav.php";?>
        <!-- END LEFT NAV -->


   <!-- START SLIDE SHOW -->            <div class="smallblock">


<div class="smallblock">
               <?php echo $details['htmlDesc'];?>
            </div>

           <div id="footer">
        Copyright Lilypad Leisure 2011 - <a href="#">Terms of Sale</a> - <a href="#">Sitemap</a>
    </div><!-- END FOOTER -->
    </div><!-- END CONTENT -->
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would this be a good option: To add the #slider{left:-40px; top:-15px;} then add *#slider{left:0x; top:0;}

Comment: If it works in IE, but not the other browsers, then your markup is wrong. Tis better to write your markup correctly for the modern browsers and then hack IE. Never, ever trust IE to do anything right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your IE-specific styles in a separate CSS file and then include that file in your HTML like so:

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" /><![endif]-->
```

These are called [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). The reverse of this also works by putting `if !IE` in the tag instead.

Comment: thanks, but im stil stuck with the width of the slider being 50px smaller in all but ie

Comment: Are you asking for CSS code to help fix the issue as well? It doesn't look like you're using a [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). This could help fix the problem as each browser has different default stylesheets, a reset stylesheet gives you an identical starting point in all browsers.

Comment: SWEET all my problems have just been solved thanks so much. This is going to save me so much time in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IE conditional comments](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments):

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
  <link style="text/css" href="http://path.to/non-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap anything you want IE to ignore in a conditional comment, like this:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
IE will ignore whatever is put here.
<!--<![endif]-->
```