# IE conditional comments

Tags: html, conditional-comments

Why this line doesn't work?

```
<!--[if !IE]>--><link rel="Stylesheet" runat="server" href="Styles/IE.css" /><!--<![endif]-->
```

Is it something not supported in newer version of IE?

Please assist, thanks.

Comment: Check what your conditional comment is doing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5059701/2564301 for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`<!--[if IE]> <![endif]-->`

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

you have your opening and closing wrong. sorry for brief answer, I'm on my mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now
>   treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The easy fix is to add an special META tag to tell to IE to emulate IE9

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

This is a quick fix but the long-term solution is to remove the dependency from the code.